# Split by only first hashtag, then get value before and after it PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, split

Say I have a string that contains this: `hey#whatsup` and I would want to get "hey" stored in one variable and "whatsup" stored in the other. But if there is any hashtags after the first, it should just become a part of the second variable.

So for example if I have a string that contains `hey#whatsup#imdave` it would save `hey` and `whatsup#imdave`.

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/explode   3rd argument for the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explode:**

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split apart the string by a delimeter (#) and set the limit to 2 so the array returned by the explode function can only contain a maximum of 2 items. Then simply access the elements of the array by index number:

```
$string = "hey#whatsup#imdave";
$pieces = explode("#", $string, 2);

echo $pieces[0]; //hey
echo $pieces[1]; //whatsup#imdave
```

Answer (score 3):

You can limit the number of parts with the third parameter of explode:

```
list($var1, $var2) = explode('#', $yourstr, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(.*?)(#.*)$
```

This should give you the result.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iX5xR2/25